# Why my SVG's rendering very small in IE9 browsers as compared to other browsers?

Tags: svg

Why my SVG's rendering very small in IE9 browsers as compared to other browsers?
Check it on :
http://jsfiddle.net/manisha_dayal/BhL5h/

CODE:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 465 500">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient y2="-4.464" x2="9.31253" y1="-4.464" x1="9.06029" id="linearGradient5389-288" xlink:href="#linearGradient5281-60-75"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient5281-60-75">
   <stop offset="0" id="stop5283-4-81" stop-color="#00bc00"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient y2="-1.96423" x2="5.56889" y1="-1.96423" x1="5.52626" id="linearGradient5358-257" xlink:href="#linearGradient5281-6-7-44"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient5281-6-7-44">
   <stop offset="0" id="stop5283-8-7-44" stop-color="#00bc00"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>

   <path fill="#803300" stroke="#4f0000" stroke-width="1.63124" d="m175.179688,386.799622c0,0 2.236053,0.28125 2.236359,16.800903c0,0.249329 -0.117767,0.124695 -0.117767,0.124695c0,0 4.190033,1.643066 5.060883,-0.748169c0.521469,-1.430542 -1.075348,1.471313 0.117767,0c0,0 -1.294525,-14.932739 3.295624,-27.626404c4.590118,-12.693665 -2.82486,-1.74231 -2.82486,-1.74231l-3.88385,13.191284l-2.589325,-3.608948l-1.29483,3.608948z" id="path5340" stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
    <path fill="url(#linearGradient5389-288)" stroke="#006500" stroke-width="1.63124" id="path3067" d="m154.31485,366.880066c0,0 27.001648,-0.080078 22.36261,18.915894c-0.197449,0.808472 -22.480286,9.084473 -22.36261,-18.915894z" stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
    <path fill="#008000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" id="path5410" d="m158.293701,370.173401c0,0 1.708588,4.247437 16.853973,14.874146c4.774017,3.34967 -16.853973,-14.874146 -16.853973,-14.874146z" stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
    <path fill="url(#linearGradient5358-257)" stroke="#006500" stroke-width="1.63124" id="path3067-8" d="m214.873505,343.743317c0,0 -3.808258,43.607941 -30.013,31.236115c-0.7211,-0.340454 -14.005951,-32.605011 30.013,-31.236115z" stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
    <path fill="#008000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" id="path5410-9" d="m202.954803,354.108612c0,0 -9.3685,8.154877 -17.436462,19.707367c-2.391663,3.424561 17.436462,-19.707367 17.436462,-19.707367z" stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
   <path fill="#005900" stroke="#084708" stroke-width="0" d="m167.58728,404.461884c0,0 -3.645798,-4.193726 -12.141418,-4.239349c-3.093018,-1.404694 8.388412,3.332947 7.573563,5.931885c2.193863,2.063873 20.251053,1.585205 22.153366,0.386536c13.504608,1.593384 5.851257,-1.770721 12.247177,-0.591553c4.639633,-13.084442 8.780899,-4.412567 9.502029,-6.244659c-0.358047,0.504974 -6.177658,-6.651428 -13.17511,3.11554c-1.58197,-1.817108 -0.340118,-6.438782 2.154877,-9.259857c-6.068848,2.962555 -3.955688,3.255798 -9.720398,9.497223c-0.563629,-1.858063 -3.688263,-0.623657 0.117111,-10.350433c-7.222672,1.65155 -5.35704,14.027435 -6.14537,11.844543c-0.788361,-2.181915 -6.210281,-9.869324 -13.734482,-10.934387c0.586411,1.125366 10.06958,5.845795 7.912262,11.765533c-4.269089,-2.511169 -6.177917,-9.453339 -14.240829,-10.067078c4.514236,2.352417 6.908157,4.650513 7.497223,9.146057l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0z" id="path10811" stroke-miterlimit="4"/>
  <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="409.50003" width="343.59283" y="-1" x="-1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try adding a `width` and a `height`-attribute to svg (`width="4cm"` e.g.)

Comment: viewBox="0 0 465 500" is taking care of the width and height of the view port...

Comment: No! The viewbox denotes the internal coordinate system for data inside of the svg file. The width and height attributes denote the external measurements of the image. Besides, without any scale, the values are useless for the displaying software...

Comment: See answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not specify the `width` and `height`. This enables the displaying software to chose a size on it's own.

To specify a size, just add `width` and `height`-Attributes to the `svg`-element.

The `viewBox`-attribute you specified denotes the size and position of the inner coordinate system of the svg. The values you used inside your position attributes (`x`, ...) refer to the coordinate system given by this four values. The first two intergers denote the 0-point of the coordinate system while the second two values denote the width and height of the image in units of the inner coordinate system. If you denote `viewBox="0 0 465 500"`, the points visible in the image last from (0, 0) to (456, 500).

The `width` and `height`-attributes denote the external size of the image. These should be given with a unit (`4cm` for example). These attributes tell the displaying software, how big the image should be drawn.

If you chose `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` and   `width="4cm" height="3cm"` the point (100, 100) in inner coordinates refer to the point (4cm, 4cm) in outer coordinates.

Comment: I edited viewBox="0 0 100 100" and width="4cm" height="3cm" But the Image disappears. Not working

Comment: viewBox - Gets a value that indicates how a graphic scales to fit a container element and this can use this behavior to zoom in or zoom out of rendered SVG content.